# Is there any "key-value" pair like data structure in linux kernel?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, data-structures, linux-kernel

For example,I want to store Pid to Name mapping in some data structure. So that, we can quickly check if some given pid is already stored or not. Can you suggest some data structure in linux kernel for that ?

Comment: Red-black trees are commonly used for larger mappings. The kernel implementation is called rbtree.

Comment: @Ulfalizer I am looking for something simple. If not then rbtree is there.

Answer (score 3):

There is map data structure in kernel, but it is not general purpose map. It maps identification number (UID) to a pointer. This is how you define it for example :

```
  struct idr map;
  idr_init(&map);
```

and then you use `idr_get_new ( struct idr * idp,void * ptr,int * id);` function to insert new element into the map

Comment: I know about IDR but I don't know if there is some way to use IDR for generic "key-value" purpose.